# Java addition with pre incrementor gives different result depending on using the brackets

Tags: java

I playing around with Java and I have come across this. I am wondering why this gives the result of `7.0`:

```
float x = 3f;
int y = 4;
System.out.println(x+++y); // 7.0
```

And not `8.0`, like it does here when we use brackets?

```
System.out.println(x+(++y)); // 8.0
```

Comment: Unary operators tend to have higher precedence than binary operators.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was the other way around.

Comment: [Here the Java operator precedence table](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/), where `()` has operator precedence over `++` and `++` has operator precedence over `+`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't think this settles the question. In both considered interpretation: `(x++) + y` and `x + (++y)` the unary operator takes precedence. 
I tried to find clarification in the Java Spec but couldn't. I guess is something about parsing from left to right, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example evaluates to `x++ + y` but your second example evaluates to, as expected, `x + ++y`

### `x++ + y`

```
Extract the value from x // x = 3
Extract the value from y // y = 4
Add them // sum = 7
Add 1 to x // x = 4
```

### `x + ++y`

```
Extract the value from x // x = 3
Add 1 to y // y = 5
Extract the value from y // y = 5
Add them // sum = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Java thinks you're trying to do a (x++ + y) inside the println.
So it first use the `x` as it is to add it with `y` and then apply the `++` to the x.
Java goes from left to right.